# Unable to create PDF graphics of Database layout using phpmyadmin

Tags: phpmyadmin, data-visualization

I have phpMyAdmin 3.4.2 setup on a Windows 7 system. And following versions of PHP and Mysql are installed -

- PHP Version 5.3.6
- mysqlnd 5.0.8-dev - 20102224 - $Revision: 308673 $  (appears in the Client API version   section of phpinfo())

The section `Currently phpMyAdmin can:` in the PMA documentation (following the documentation link of my PMA installation) displays the following-

- create PDF graphics of your Database layout

Which means PDF graphics is viewing is supported in the version I am using.

But I am not able to see any option in the PMA UI to visualize the Db architecture. I made a fresh db, created two tables and added a foreign key constraint linking these two tables. Where does the option/tab to visualize appear?

What am I missing? Any ideas?

Thanks

**Update**
Following are the dbs present -

```
show databases; ->
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| lab                |
| mysql              |
| openx              |
| test               |
+--------------------+
```

**Further Update**
 I executed the `create_tables.sql` file successfully and saw a new table `phpmyadmin` created, having 10 tables, i.e. pma_pdf_pages etc. Then I followed config storage doc. I was not having any `config.inc.php`. I renamed the `config.sample.inc.php` to `config.inc.php`, verified that the file is being loaded and then uncommented these lines -

```
 $cfg['Servers'][$i]['pmadb'] = 'phpmyadmin';
 $cfg['Servers'][$i]['pdf_pages'] = 'pma_pdf_pages';
```

Still not getting the designer tab.

**Update 3**
Uncommented all these lines in config file -

```
/* Storage database and tables */
 $cfg['Servers'][$i]['pmadb'] = 'phpmyadmin';
 $cfg['Servers'][$i]['bookmarktable'] = 'pma_bookmark';
 $cfg['Servers'][$i]['relation'] = 'pma_relation';
 $cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_info'] = 'pma_table_info';
 $cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_coords'] = 'pma_table_coords';
 $cfg['Servers'][$i]['pdf_pages'] = 'pma_pdf_pages';
 $cfg['Servers'][$i]['column_info'] = 'pma_column_info';
 $cfg['Servers'][$i]['history'] = 'pma_history';
 $cfg['Servers'][$i]['tracking'] = 'pma_tracking';
 $cfg['Servers'][$i]['designer_coords'] = 'pma_designer_coords';
 $cfg['Servers'][$i]['userconfig'] = 'pma_userconfig';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you've selected the database, there should be a "Designer" tab at the top, between "Import" and "Operations" on my install.

Comment: That tab is not there. I have `Export`, `Import` and `More` tabs.

Comment: Looks like you need the "phpmyadmin" db... is that present on your system?

Comment: Please check my update. Where should this db be present?

Comment: Right, in order for the designer tab to be available (and other features, like database table tracking), you need to install the phpmyadmin database which stores the results of these extended phpmyadmin features. Here is their wiki page: http://wiki.phpmyadmin.net/pma/Configuration_storage. If that is not enough by itself, hopefully it will point you in the right direction.

Comment: your answer sounds correct, so a +1, but still I could not successfully bring up the designer tab. Please check my **Further Updates** section.

Comment: Based on your updates, maybe you did not create the "control user?" This is the mysql user that has access to the new table plus it needs to be configured in the config file - just like any php/mysql script, we need to let it access its table (little weird in this context I know but maybe that's all you have left to do). Good luck!

Comment: yes I did not create the "control user". Now done everything mentioned in http://wiki.phpmyadmin.net/pma/controluser. Logged into phpmyadmin as `pma` user, but still no success. Any ideas?? Check my **update 3**

Comment: I did some reinstallation of apache, php after that. I don't exactly remember how but I checked that later after few days and the designer tab appeared. So, installing the phpmyadmin database is the answer... accepted :)

Answer (score 0):

The 'Designer' Tab needs to be enabled on WAMP, MAMP, and maybe LAMP setups. It involves editing a config file depending upon which operating system you use. There's a tutorial here http://debian.sreenadh.in/2008/11/28/how-to-enable-designer-in-phpmyadmin/ or you can just google 'Enable Designer Tab phpmyadmin' to find other resources specific to your OS.